# Combining the values of an array with the values of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an attributes array which is defined by me and  I get an hash  both of them which I need to combine into an output array. Please let me know the simplest way to do this.

**attributes** = [:user_id, :project_id, :task_id, :date, :time_spent, :comment]

**entry_hash** = {"User"=>1, "Project"=>[8], "Task"=>[87], "Date"=>"05/22/2017", "Time (Hours)"=>"1", "Comment"=>"yes"}

When it is combined I want a hash like

**Output** = {"user_id"=>1, "project_id"=>8, "task_id"=>87,
         "date"=>6/22/2017,"time_spent"=>1,"comment"=>"yes"}

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
attributes = [:user_id, :project_id, :task_id, :date, :time_spent, :comment]
# puts attributes.inspect
entry_hash = {"User"=>1, "Project"=>[8], "Task"=>[87], "Date"=>"05/22/2017", "Time (Hours)"=>"1", "Comment"=>"yes"}
# puts entry_hash.inspect

output = {}
a = 0
entry_hash.each do |key,value|
    if value.class == Array
        output[attributes[a]] = value.first.to_s
        #output[attributes[a]] = value.first.to_i   //also you can convert them into int
    else
        output[attributes[a]] = value
    end
    a += 1

end
#puts output.inspect
#{:user_id=>1, :project_id=>"8", :task_id=>"87", :date=>"05/22/2017", :time_spent=>"1", :comment=>"yes"}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped! I have another problem now. When i try to insert the output hash into the database by doing model.create!(output) it is not able to do so.  any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Archie123 What type of error did you get ? and what model it is can you show its attributes ?